# appengine search index reclaim space of deleted documents

Tags: google-app-engine

After creating a search index in appengine, adding a lot of documents, found out that the data has an issue. Deleted all documents and re-indexed them but the usage space of the index keeps incrementing and never decrement when deleting documents. We are approaching the 10GB limit and not sure how we can reclaim the space of all the deleted documents.

Answer (score 0):

Have you run the "gcloud datastore cleanup-indexes index.yaml" command, after having removed unwanted index entries from the index.yaml configuration file? You may find more detail on the "Cloud Datastore Indexes" documentation [page](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/datastore/indexes#index-limits).